# How to install ALX drivers for an AR8171 network adaptor in OMV

Tags: networking, drivers

I bought a shiny new ASRock FM2A88X Extreme4+ motherboard (which I chose specifically for the plentiful expansion slots) to run my shiny new file server. During the installation of Open Media Vault, the installer failed to identify the network adaptor (according to the ASRock [website](http://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/FM2A88X%20Extreme4+/?cat=Specifications), a Qualcomm Atheros  AR8171 ). Googling lead me to believe it uses the ALX driver. I selected the entry in the installer, however it failed to initialise. I decided to try a manual install of an updated driver, so downloaded the latest  [Backports Driver Pack](https://wiki.debian.org/alx) for the ALX driver (via my desktop mackine onto a USB stick). However when I went to compile it on the OMV server, it complained saying MAKE isn't installed. To add salt to injury, when I tried to download MAKE, the installation instructions give direction to make MAKE (which I cannot do without MAKE installed).

For the life of me I cannot find a stand-alone installer (such as a .deb file) for the ALX driver. All other instructions I've found online need an internet connection to do (adding sources etc) which I cannot do without a working network adaptor!

Does anyone out there know how to fix this??

Comment: Can you post the out put of `lspci`?

Comment: Command not found

Comment: What about `lshw -C network`?

Comment: Also command not found

Comment: Booted into SolydX (also debian based) and ran lspci. The Ethernet line says Qualcomm Atheros QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet rev 10

Comment: Does [this help](https://wiki.debian.org/alx)

Comment: I have seen that page, however it requires internet access

Comment: Well you need access to install the backport, and reboot....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Success!
I managed to get hold of an old PCI network card with an Intel chip on it that worked with the OMV kernel drivers. Then managed to hack together a few different tutorials to get it finally working.

1. Fit the secondary network card and boot up. Follow the install prompts for OMV.
2. Log into the terminal console using user: `root` and the password set during install.
3. `apt-get install make aptitude hwinfo`
4. Type `nano /etc/apt/sources.list` to edit the package sources and add the following lines to the bottom of the repositories list:

> # Backported packages for Debian 7 Wheezy
>       deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ wheezy-backports main

5. `aptitude update`
6. `aptitude -t wheezy-backports install linux-image-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,')`
7. Press CTRL-ALT-DEL and wait for the system to reboot.
8. `hwinfo` should show both network devices (eth0 and eth1)
9. Shutdown and remove the secondary network card.